# Implementación de excepciones en una funcion de borrado

Tags: python

```
 try:
     borrar_nombre=(input("Introduzca el Nombre del Usuario a Borrar: "))
     for e in usuario.copy(): 
       if e["Nombre"] == borrar_nombre: usuario.remove(e)
 
  except Exception:
```

Intenté poner las excepciones definidas por Python y no funciono y luego intenté crear la clase excepción y tampoco. Nunca me da error es una función de borrado de nombres y tengo que controlar las excepciones.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. Para tener algo que controlar, primero debes tener código que pueda producir una excepción y provocarla. No estoy seguro que sea el caso de tu código. ¿Qué excepción específicamente estás esperando que ocurra y controlar? ¿bajo qué circunstancias?

Comment: tengo una lista de diccionarios. y cree esa funcion que para borrar y mantenga el orden del diccionario. pero el problema me da a la hora de crear las excepciones para controlar lo que pongan. pongo las predeterminadas por el sistema y no me funciona y por el otro lado intento crear la clase excepcion para intentar crear las mias propias pero tampoco me funciona

Comment: Vamos paso a paso. Primero una que exista. ¿cuál esperas provocar? ¿bajo qué circunstancias?

Comment: intento controlar lo que se introduzca. ya sea un nombre que no esta en la lista de  diccionario, que este mal escrito o cualquier error que se pueda preever

Comment: "cualquier error" suele ser bastante complicado y no es la manera de _manejar_ las excepciones. Es más bien, al revés. La idea es que controlas los errores específicos que te interesan y que sabes qué hacer con ellos, y dejas seguir su camino a todo el resto. El que exista el nombre, por lo que veo, ya lo haces con un if, por lo que nunca va a dar error, lo cual también me parece bien.

Comment: pero tambien tiene q ser si pone alguna letra incorrecta o un numero en el nombre

Comment: No existe ningun error en Python que salte ante esas condiciones. La mejor opción es crear un if.

Comment: No es un buen ejemplo para usar excepciones, de hecho no son necesarias porque el `for` tiene que recorrer todos los elementos para buscar una coincidencia con `borrar_nombre`. Si el elemento actual no coincide con esa variable, no da error, simplemente devuelve `False` y el ciclo continúa con el próximo item. Pero podrías implementarlas haciendo una variante, que esa lista de diccionarios sea un archivo **json** o **txt** (por ejemplo) y ahí puedes capturar varias excepciones, por ejemplo: si el archivo existe o si es escribible.

Comment: entonces la otra forma para implementar las excepciones es  con un if delimitando los posibles errores que se pueden ir introduciendo. ??

Comment: es la unica forma de poderlo hacer? para poder controlar las excepciones

Comment: Si lo que querés hacer es mandar tus propias excepciones y capturarlas con un try-except para mostrarselas al usuario (algo que uso mucho para validación) podés hacer dentro de un if que, si lo ingresado no es valido, por ejemplo, haga "raise ValueError(mensaje)" que manda un error de tipo valueerror con el mensaje "mensaje". Te recomiendo crear clases derivadas de exception personalizadas para evitar falsos positivos.